# VirtualBox full screen and proper scale for Debian 10

Tags: debian, virtualbox, fullscreen

I want to have my virtualbox of debian 10 scale properly (not being weirdly stretched out or thin when I adjust it in "Scaled-Mode" under the "View" tab).

Right now I have it in scale-mode, which looks alright when I make the screen as tall as possible and about half the width of my total screen width.

I've heard about going into Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image..., but I haven't been able to actually make that work or find a tutorial that seem compatible with Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

In this [Install VBAddons](https://www.linuxbabe.com/debian/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-debian-9-stretch), you may find more on how to install virtualbox addons.

EDIT: you might as well be unable to run the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` file. Indeed, it is not executable yet. You may copy the whole addons folder (let us say in a folder and change its permission ==> suppose you copy it in /home/user/folder). Then run the following commands to launch it

```bsh
cd /home/users/folder
chmod +x VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

However, this method recompiles a part of the addons and may fail. If it fails, that means that some of the dependencies are not installed in your virtual machine (most probably kernel-headers or the compiler chain). Don't worry, i know it is for Debian 9 but i also have tested it on Debian 10.

If it fails, you may see [HOWTO: Install Linux Guest Additions + Xorg config](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15679#p65521). This second forum explicitly shows how to install all the necessary elements before attempting to install VBoxAddons

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using VirtualBox 6.x from the offical VB repository? Typically the VB packages from there automatically download the guest additions ISO and mounts them for you once you choose it in the Devices menu (at least in Linux environments with an installed desktop).

Also: have you added your user to the vboxusers group?